# Query DB on MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

Totally new for MySQL. I am looking for best solution for get a report from Database.

Here are the details:

**Customer_order** - `order_id`, `customer_id`, `order_name`, `order_price`, `order_store_id`

**Customer_details** - `customer_id`, `customer_name`, `customer_emp_id`

**Customer_order_items** - `order_id`, `customer_id`, `product_name`

I am trying to get all the details from **Customer_order_items**, **customer_order**, **customer_details** and show up in a result by giving specific data to `order_store_id`

So I was trying the following:

```
SELECT d.customer_name, d.company_id, p.store_id, p.order_id, a.product_id, a.service_id
FROM customer_master d
JOIN customer_orders p ON d.customer_id = p.customer_id
JOIN customer_order_items a ON a.customer_id = d.customer_id
WHERE p.order_store_id =  "000020"
```

I get the results but strangely I am getting all double, triple values.

What should I do to get my results correct is my query correct?

Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You should add LEFT to the JOIN condition

The LEFT JOIN force to SELECT all rows of the LEFT table (of JOIN condition) and the corresponding rows in the RIGHT table.

```
SELECT d.customer_name, d.company_id, p.store_id, p.order_id, a.product_id, a.service_id
FROM customer_master d
LEFT JOIN customer_orders p ON d.customer_id = p.customer_id
LEFT JOIN customer_order_items a ON a.customer_id = d.customer_id
WHERE p.order_store_id =  "000020"
```

Comment: Does it make a difference?

Comment: yes, LEFT JOIN forces to select the rows of the table in the left side of the JOIN and the corresponding rows of the table in the right side of the JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your query is wrong and your db design is wrong (why would you have customer id at order items level?) Assuming you have a link on order number between orders and order_items I think I can replicate your issue like this

```
ariaDB [sandbox]> select * from customers;
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
|    1 | John |
|    2 | Jane |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from orders;
+-------------+---------+------------+------------+
| ordernumber | cust_id | orderdate  | shipdate   |
+-------------+---------+------------+------------+
|           1 |       1 | 2016-01-01 | 2016-02-01 |
|           2 |       1 | 2016-02-01 | NULL       |
+-------------+---------+------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from order_details;
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+---------+
| id   | ordernumber | quantityordered | quotedprice | cust_id |
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+---------+
|    1 |           1 |              10 |          10 |       1 |
|    2 |           1 |              20 |          20 |       1 |
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Given this data I would expect to get 2 rows in my result using your query (as amended for my data)

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select c.id,c.name,o.ordernumber,o.orderdate,od.quantityordered
    -> from customers c
    -> join orders o on o.cust_id = c.id
    -> join order_details od on od.cust_id = c.id
    -> order by ordernumber;
```

But in fact I get 4 rows

```
+------+------+-------------+------------+-----------------+
| id   | name | ordernumber | orderdate  | quantityordered |
+------+------+-------------+------------+-----------------+
|    1 | John |           1 | 2016-01-01 |              20 |
|    1 | John |           1 | 2016-01-01 |              10 |
|    1 | John |           2 | 2016-02-01 |              10 |
|    1 | John |           2 | 2016-02-01 |              20 |
+------+------+-------------+------------+-----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

because of the join to order_details on customer id.
A more rational approach is to cascade the joins to that order_details are joined to orders on ordernumber (using a left join just in case an order has no order_details)

```
ariaDB [sandbox]> select c.id,c.name,o.ordernumber,o.orderdate,od.quantityordered
    -> from customers c
    -> join orders o on o.cust_id = c.id
    -> left join order_details od on od.ordernumber = o.ordernumber
    -> order by ordernumber;
+------+------+-------------+------------+-----------------+
| id   | name | ordernumber | orderdate  | quantityordered |
+------+------+-------------+------------+-----------------+
|    1 | John |           1 | 2016-01-01 |              20 |
|    1 | John |           1 | 2016-01-01 |              10 |
|    1 | John |           2 | 2016-02-01 |            NULL |
+------+------+-------------+------------+-----------------+
```

Which gives me the 3 rows I expect.

Comment: That is exactly happening. What should I do?

Comment: Try the last query (amending for your data)

Comment: Do you have indexes?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Run explain against the query and implement any suggested keys. How many records do you have in each of the tables? Does the query complete in command line sql? Have you accurately transcribed the query? Are there any locks against the tables. Are you running over a slow server connection?

Comment: We are running this on AWS. I have double checked the query. We have about 44K data in order_items and 20K data in orders

Comment: I cannot help with AWS issues. If you have a supported service with amazon I suggest you take it up with them or raise a new question properly taggged and described.

Comment: Don't think this is an AWS issue. It is purely Database query. It can be the same issue in any web server. Just struggling to fix the query part.